# Content Search engine

Tags: content-management-system, google-search-api

I have number of files in my server. I need to create a local intranet site where user can search a word and in turn it should return the files which contain this word. I need to know what kind of search engine can I use for this. Few told me to go with google search api. Is it possible to use google search api for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org) which is used in search engines like [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). They both use [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) for indexing files and allow you to do free text search on any keyword in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an intranet that has a document store, the way I created a content search was to add the document name, descriptions and keywords as fields in the database with a field for the location and a field for the file name.  I am a fan of ajax so I used this to find documents on a type and find basis.

There may be other ways of doing this without the need for a database, however I find it gives more control and allows users of the intranet to upload documents and give detailed descriptions of what the document contains and what its about.

it works really well.  for example, people searching for a staff hand book - my not type in "Staff handbook", they may type in "Staff Rules", "Staff Guidelines", by having the additional fields in the database that records keywords and description will allow for better results from a search where as just searching on a filename will require a more precise search (unless the content of the actual file can be searched).

Well that's my opinion on this and it works really well.  I haven't posted the code as it is coded in classic asp (yes I know, we are currently working to moving to ASP.NET but its a long process).

Comment: No it doesn't, I just posted a solution that I used to search for documents/files stored within the intranet. As I said in my answer this solution works brilliantly and does not require any third party support so you would have full control.

Comment: Some storage layers also have built in search engines. Have you selected a storage layer for your intranet?